# groupby data with columns that have mixed data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Lets say I had this sample of a mixed dataset:

```
df:

Property              Name      Date of entry   Old data      Updated data
City                     Jim    1/7/2021      Jacksonville    Miami 
State                    Jack   1/8/2021      TX              CA
Zip                     Joe     2/2/2021     11111            22222
Address                Harry    2/3/2021     123 lane         123 street
Telephone              Lisa     3/1/2021     111-111-11111    333-333-3333
Email                  Tammy    3/2/2021     tammy@yahoo.com  tammy@gmail.com
Date Product Ordered    Lisa    3/3/2021     2/1/2021          2/10/2021
Order count            Tammy    3/4/2021      2                3
```

I'd like to group by all this data starting with property and have it look like this:

```
grouped:

Property    Name      Date of entry    Old data   Updated Data
City        names1     date 1          data 1      data 2
            names2     date 2          data 1      data 2
            names3     date 3          data 1      data 2

State       names1     date 1          data 1      data 2
            names2     date 2          data 1      data 2
            names3     date 3          data 1      data 2
```

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Property','Name','Date of entry','Old Data', 'updated data'])
             .size(),columns=['Count'])
grouped
```

*and I get a type error saying: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'*

Is there some sort of formatting that I need to do to the df['Old data'] & df['Updated data'] columns to allow them to be added to the groupby?

```
added data types:

Property: Object
Name: Object
Date of entry: datetime
Old data: Object
Updated data: Object
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Show us `df.dtypes`, or equivalently `df.info()`. Looks like 'Date of entry' is datetime, but can't see why the other columns would be 'int', they should be object.

Comment: Also, the trailing `.size()` on your `df.groupby(...)` seems wrong. Try removing it. And there's a syntax error in that the bracket opened by `df.groupby(['Property',...` is never closed. Unless you omitted some code.

Comment: tried removing the .size() method and still getting the same issue and ya bracket was a typo, but good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I modified your initial data to get a better view of the output.

You can try with `pivot_table` instead of `groupby`:

```
df.pivot_table(index = ['Property', 'Name', 'Date of entry'], aggfunc=lambda x: x)
```

Output:

```
                                                 Old data     Updated data
Property             Name  Date of entry                                  
Address              Harry 2/3/2021              123 lane       123 street
                     Lisa  2/3/2021              123 lane       123 street
City                 Jack  1/8/2021                    TX            Miami
                     Jim   1/7/2021          Jacksonville            Miami
                     Tammy 1/8/2021                    TX            Miami
Date Product Ordered Lisa  3/3/2021              2/1/2021        2/10/2021
Email                Tammy 3/2/2021       tammy@yahoo.com  tammy@gmail.com
Order count          Jack  3/4/2021                     2                3
                     Tammy 3/4/2021                     2                3
State                Jack  1/8/2021                    TX               CA
Telephone            Lisa  3/1/2021         111-111-11111     333-333-3333
Zip                  Joe   2/2/2021                 11111            22222
```

The whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = '''Property              Name      Date of entry   Old data      Updated data
City                     Jim    1/7/2021      Jacksonville    Miami 
City                     Jack   1/8/2021      TX    Miami 
State                    Jack   1/8/2021      TX              CA
Zip                     Joe     2/2/2021     11111            22222
Order count            Jack    3/4/2021      2                3
Address                Harry    2/3/2021     123 lane         123 street
Telephone              Lisa     3/1/2021     111-111-11111    333-333-3333
Address                Lisa    2/3/2021     123 lane         123 street
Email                  Tammy    3/2/2021     tammy@yahoo.com  tammy@gmail.com
Date Product Ordered    Lisa    3/3/2021     2/1/2021          2/10/2021
Order count            Tammy    3/4/2021      2                3
City                     Tammy   1/8/2021      TX    Miami 
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=0, skipinitialspace=True, sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')

print(df.pivot_table(index = ['Property', 'Name', 'Date of entry'], aggfunc=lambda x: x))
```

Comment: that worked great! But in my data I have blanks and it put an empty lists in each spot, is there a way to remove that? Also, it altered the time format, for example my dates are now: '2021-07-01T00:00:00:000000000'. I tried modifying the column to a datetime using the to_datetime method and got a type error that says: unhashable type: numpy.ndarray'

Comment: I added 'date of entry' to the function and it seemed to do the trick! df.pivot_table(index = ['Property', 'Name', **'date of entry'**], aggfunc=lambda x: x)